# Parent Div = Float Left. Child Div Not Displaying Text

Tags: html, css, parent

So i have a parent div (box one) with a float: left. My child div (hover-state) is basically just a hover state. The child div has 2 text elements and an underline. The underline shows but the text elements are not showing. if you look at the jsfiddle, and hover over the white box, you'll see what i mean.

```
        <div class="box one">
            <div class="hover-state">

                <h3>This Artist</h3>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <h4>some text</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fx9f6xb/

Comment: This is really bugging me... however you should use the border property instead of a lined div :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have `font-size: 0` in `.roster` so it makes inherit to all childrens. Reset your code as this:

```
.roster > div {
     font-size: 1rem; 
}
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/8fx9f6xb/1/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `font-size` or change it. This is inherited by all the children and nothing gets displayed:

```
.roster > div {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fq0jsapb/**